# Is it possible to have such kind of two functions?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose there are two continuous functions $f_1(x)\geq 0,f_2(x)\geq 0$. Further assume that both are decreasing and $f_1(x)\geq f_2(x)$. Is it possible that $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ touch the horizontal line (for first time) at same value of $x$. I think it is not possible. Is my thinking wrong?

Comment: If you go with $\ge$, you can even say $f_1(x) = f_2(x)$

Comment: @dxiv but they are not decreasing functions

Comment: @dxiv Those are not decreasing functions.

Comment: @Sudix hmmm you are right but what happens if $f_1(x)>f_2(x)$? Can my thinking be wrong in this case?

Comment: @ThomasBladt Then try $f_1(x) = 2-2x$ and $f_2(x)=1-x$ on $[0,1]$, both constant outside $[0,1]$.

Comment: "what happens if $f_1(x)>f_2(x)$?" If $f_2$ hits the horizontal then given that $f_1,f_2\geq 0$, decreasing, and continuous, $f_2$ would be identically zero once it hits the axis. If $f_1$ hits the horizontal then $f_1(x)=f_2(x)=0$ for $x$ large enough, which violates $f_1(x)>f_2(x)$.

Comment: @dxiv If you include 1, then we have $f_1(1)=2-2 \,\,=0 = \,\,1-1 = f_2(x)$.

Comment: @Sudix Right, of course. The functions *must* be equal at some point if they have a common zero. Note however that $f_1(x) \gt f_2(x)$ for $x \lt 1$ i.e. left of $1$.

Comment: @dxiv How about your function defined instead on $(0,1)$?

Comment: @Sudix You could take $f_1(2x)$ and $f_2(2x)$ using the functions defined in my other comment, then the common $0$ would be at $1/2 \in (0,1)$ if that's what you meant.

Comment: @dxiv On their whole domain, $f1,f2$ fulfill the requirement $f1(x)>f2(x)$, yet you can say $\lim_{x\nearrow1}f_1(x) = \lim_{x\nearrow1}f_2(x) = 0$

Comment: @Sudix That's true, but not what the OP asked: `Is it possible that f1(x) and f2(x) touch the horizontal line (for first time) at same value of x`. The question as stated is about a value $x=x_0$ where $f_1(x_0)=f_2(x_0)=0$, not about limits.

Answer (score 0):

You say both are decreasing and non-negative so if one of them reach to horizontal line it can not increase and since it can not be negative it will stay on horizontal line and after its first zero it will be constant and equal to zero.it is possible but after they will be equal to zero.for instance -2x+2 and -x+1 between (0,1) and zero after 1